# What is the relationship between Turing Machines with a finite tape and Finite State Automata?

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata

I seem to recall from an undergraduate class that for a Turing Machine with a finite tape there will always exist a corresponding Finite State Automata, but I've been unable to find this confirmed anywhere on the internet. Is this actually the case or am I misremembering?

Comment: How many possible states will a Turing machine with a finite tape have?

Comment: It will be finitely many but, as the below answer shows, that's not necessarily sufficient for drawing an equivalence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "finite tape". If you bound the length of the tape by some function of the input, then no - you can recognize non-regular languages. For example, consider [LBAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton).

But if you mean a *bounded* tape, where the tape has $k$ cells for some fixed $k$, then yes - you indeed get a model which is equivalent to DFAs.

To prove this, consider what information you need to determined the future of a run of a TM: you need the contents of the tape, the location of the head, and the state. If the tape has a constant number of cells, and the alphabet is fixed, then you have a constant number of configurations, which you can encode as states of a finite automaton.

Comment: Your answer for the bounded tape was exactly what I was looking for . Thank you!

Comment: @Shaull in bounded shell infinite-regular languages acceptance is possible?

Comment: @user19121278 - could you elaborate? I didn't understand your question. Also, is "shell" a typo?